# Solving Average value theorem over an unknown interval

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$f(x) = 2^{x-2}+1$. I now have to detirmine the value of $a$, such that the average value of the function $f(x)$ on the interval $[2,a]$ is 8.

So that means I have to solve this integral but I'm not sure how: $1/(a-2)\int^a_2(2^{x-2}+1)dx$. How do I isolate a?

Comment: Hint:  it helps to write $2^x=e^{x\ln 2}$

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps? I needed to take the integral

Comment: It is easy to integrate $e^{cx}$.

Comment: I know the integral of $2^{x-2}+1$: $(2^{x-2}/ln(2))+x$, i just know don't know how to solve for $a$

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question.  Once the integral is complete, it's just a matter of solving (an admittedly transcendental equation) for $a$.

Comment: I don't see a trivial closed answer.  Easy to solve numerically...$a=6.519$ gives an average of $8.00034$